# When Message object is recycled by Android an Android system

Tags: android

I have created a Message with obtain() method and send it through a Messenger. So when this Message is reclaimed by the system? Can I use the same Message object in the destination handler? Sometimes, I could see  this Message object contents changes by itself. So it looks like system reclaims the Message object and allocate it to any other other requesting code.
Other words , I like to know when android framework calls recycle() on a Message object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages are recycled in the framework layer once the `Handler.dispatchMessage(Message msg)` (so consecutively `Handler.handleMessage(Message msg)`) are called.

You must always obtain a new message or you will run into undefined behavior.

Please see [this example](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/os/Looper.java#137) of how `Looper` is managing the recycling of messages.

Comment: You shouldn't point to a robolectric class as an example when trying to argue about how Android works; point to actual Android source instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from [@wfranczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941095/9909307), here's a link to the `loopOnce()` method in Android's source for `Looper.java` that shows a message being dispatched and then recycled at the end of the method:

[Link to Android source](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=159?q=Looper.java&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject&gsn=loopOnce&gs=kythe%3A%2F%2Fandroid.googlesource.com%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%3Flang%3Djava%3Fpath%3Dandroid.os.Looper%2331f19057d3122bef0366b759b79facd25af449217d7130876faca9cdfb075a86)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31241187)